# Can't delete from SQLite table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I'm Doing a "take home assignment" for job interview. While I have some experience in web development, its not my forte. I am trying to delete a row in a SQLite table using a HTML DELETE button. I am using Laravel-php framework.

I've tried different solutions on google and stack Overflow, but none seem to solve the problem. I modeled my approach after this [Laracasts video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/13)

[Link to my code](https://github.com/LoganHornbuckle/AddressBook)

The blade seems to be passing the correct info ($id from $contact->id) & the controller seems to be receiving. But the given contact associated with the id isn't being deleted.

FROM BLADE:

```php
<div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($contacts as $contact)
            <tr>
                <td> {{$contact->f_name}} </td>
                <td> {{$contact->l_name}} </td>
                <td> {{$contact->address}} </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="POST" action="/delete/{{ $contact->id }}">
                        @method('DELETE')
                        @csrf

                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <button type="submit" class="button">Delete Contact</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

FROM CONTROLLER:

```php
public function delete($id) {

  Contact::find($id)->delete();

  return view('index');

}
```

FROM ROUTE:

```php
Route::delete('/delete', [
  'uses'=>'ContactController@delete',
  'as'=>'contacts.delete'
]);
```

Comment: Sorry for the messy indentation in HTML code, stackoverflow made me indent everything >= 4 lines, which threw everything off.

Comment: Is your model using soft-deletes?

Comment: Not using soft deletes.

Comment: I suggested an edit for your question if you'd like to review it. I believe it will make the code easier to read. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23388383

Comment: You need to change your `route` as following:
    `Route::delete('/delete/{id}', [
    'uses'=>'ContactController@delete',
    'as'=>'contacts.delete'
    ]);`

And it is advisable to use form action like `action="{{ route('contacts.delete', [$contact->id]) }}"` instead of `action="/delete/{{ $contact->id }}"`

Answer (score 0):

you're not getting the id on your delete method, you need to include it on the url like

```php
Route::delete('/delete/{id}', [
  'uses'=>'ContactController@delete',
  'as'=>'contacts.delete'
]);
```

in this case, you don't need to change the delete method.

you can also retrieve the id from the request object without changing the delete route, int this case you need to include the id as a hidden input on your view and your delete method will look like this

```php
public function delete(Request $request) {

  Contact::find($request->id)->delete();

  return view('index');

}
```

Comment: unfortunately when I use that delete method, i get a "Call to a member function delete() on null" error

Comment: which solution did you choose? the one with the id on the link or the one with the request object?

Comment: 2nd one, id in the request object

Comment: and the input type is hidden in view also

Comment: the code in github link is current if you need to see anything else

Comment: saw your code, try with Contact::find($request->id) , if it doesn't work try to dd($request->id) so we can check if the id is sent on the request

Comment: if the $request->id exists and the Contact::find($request->id) is null, it means that the record doesn't exists on the table

Comment: I fixed it. the problem was in index.blade.php. It was missing value="{{$contact->id}}. i wrongly assumed this was already included in http request. thanks for your help!